# How can I give FAILED status in Spring Batch

Tags: kotlin, spring-batch

I want to give FAILED status in spring batch when writer's result doesn't meet my own condition.

where can I give BatchStauts is Failed on my code?

```kotlin
// writer

    override fun write(input: MutableList<out Long>) {

        ...

            if ((-1) * result <= remainAmount) {
                println("SUCCESS")
            } else {
                println("HOW CAN I GIVE FAILED STATUS?")
            }
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
//step

    @Bean("verifyStep")
    fun verifyStoreGroupCouponStep(): Step {
        return stepBuilderFactory!!.get("verifyStep")
            .chunk<Long, Long>(10000)
            .reader(getIdReader)
            .writer(verifyWriter)
            .build()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the StepExecutionListener interface which provides method beforeStep() and afterStep().
So, when your condition does not meet set a flag in write() method and you can validate that flag in afterStep() method and inside that method you can return  ExitStatus.FAILED. As shown:

```
@Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

        if (!condition)
         return ExitStatus.FAILED;
       else
         return ExitStatus.COMPLETED; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception from your `else` block. Spring batch will mark the job as `FAILED` in `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` table.